# Why aren't my high voted questions showing up when I sort the questions page by votes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions, sorting

I have a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2339/1109) that I was trying to see what its ranking was with respect to vote count, but when I [sort the site by votes on the questions page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=votes&pagesize=50), it skips over my question (as well as all my other high vote questions).

Is this normal?

Comment: Indeed, I don't see your question where it should be on the [list of questions sorted by votes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=votes&pagesize=50). I do see it where I'd expect it if I search inside the [tag](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h-p-lovecraft) or by [author](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1109/oghmaosiris?tab=questions&sort=votes).

Comment: I also don't see your question on the sort by votes list.  How odd.

Comment: Is it some sort of time filter? If so, the Tom Bombaldi question also shouldn't be on there as it's much older than mine.

Comment: I see plenty of older questions in the sorted by votes list.  Nothing I see is unique about your question, so its absence is strange.

Comment: Its showing up now. What did someone do?

Answer (score 1):

As [you noted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/why-arent-my-high-voted-questions-showing-up-when-i-sort-the-questions-page-by#comment8062_2449) in a comment, this bug, whatever it was, has been fixed. Your question now shows up exactly where it should in [the list of all questions sorted by votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=votes&pagesize=50).